# Magnetic sensor preamplifier using op07

Tags: sensor, transducer

I am  using this circuit to amplify a sensor signal (220mV p-p) to about 5Vp-p and measuring by microcontroller ADC:

[image]

When I connect the input signal, the input voltage level goes up (changes from 220mV p-p to 600mV p-p) and the output signal is corrupted.

The input signal is 220 mv p-p, 11.5 khz.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to replace 'tuner' from your circuit to known signal, for example a signal generator set to 200mV, 11.5kHz?

Comment: Is the sensor signal a square wave?

Comment: Thanks to answer , no I  haven't signal generator at home , is the schematic true ?

Comment: Signal is sinus wave , about 11.5 to 12 khz . Before i connect signal to preamplifier , signal have 220mv p-p voltage , but when connect , input signal change to higher voltage level about 600mv p-p , why ? I think signal must increasing after amplifier not before

Comment: What is this thing you call 'tuner'? How are you measuring the input voltage? _"the output signal is corrupted"_ - Please show us the output signal.

Comment: Tuner is a lc tank to have resonance for rx signal ,  Input signal ; You can see in the photo from oscilloscope above . Have 220mv p-p . When i connect to op07 input , input signal on pin 2 of opamp increase to 500 mv p-p an , Is it normal ? When i'm increasing 56k resistor to 1M ohm , The input signal is corrected but op amp haven't output signal .